# NVIDIA Settings Persistence

Tags: nvidia, settings, persistence

I'm quite new to the whole desktop Ubuntu scene, but I'm trying to get my NVIDIA settings to persist but it has a hard time doing it.

So far I've tried doing `sudo nvidia-settings` and saving that to xorg, but when I reboot everything goes back to its default.

It also gives me a dialog on the login screen saying

```
Could not switch the monitor configuration
- could not set the configuration for CRTC444
```

I have also tried using arandr and using the shell script to run after login but I get this error.

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  56
  Current serial number in output stream:  56
```

What's going on? How do I fix this?

My monitor setup looks like this right now, GPU is a 1080TI

```
[AOC 22 INCH 1080P][ASUS 22 INCH 1080P]
              [ACER X34]
```

Comment: You have to run nvidia-settings as root and save to xorg. Do not merge org. Or you can run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Did that but still doesn't persist. In fact that's what gives me the CRTC 444 error.

Comment: If that does not work, first post your xorg.conf and the exact command you ran. Second you will then need to file a bug report with nvidia - https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/

Answer (score 1):

This exact issue drove me insane. The solution is to apply the graphics settings in more than one options menu. You must first apply your settings in the nvidia-settings menu, and then open the Displays menu (located in the All Settings menu), and hit apply there as well. I know you aren't tweaking any settings in the Displays menu, but you must click apply there anyway, so that your nvidia settings persist between reboots.

Comment: This solved my issue, actually, a couple of issues. I also had a window with black scene, couldn't change icons and window decorations and had issue with plymouth. This solved all of these issues on Ubuntu 16.04 and should be marked as valid answer.